# Moving my css message box around

Tags: css

I have the following css that creates a simple box. I have a problem moving this box to the right. What is the attribute that I can add to my stylesheet so I can adjust this box around horizontally and vertically to fit the design of my website?

```
 .ConversionBox2 {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    color: #004284;
    padding: 15px;
    float:left;
    /* Border Radius Style */
    border-radius: 15px;
   /* Mozilla Firefox Extension */
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  }
```

Comment: using left:<number> px

Comment: should I still keep float:left; and added left:20px;? it did not work

Comment: You need to post some more code to exemplify the context. As suggested, position absolute is a possibility, however, it will depend on your html structure.

Comment: I don't have much codes, I just have a table on the left side of my screen and an empty space on the right next to the table. Instead of putting my message at the bottom of the table and user need to scroll, I plan to put the message next to the table to the right this way user can see a table on the left and a message box on the right. with that css I've been able to do that but I want to move the message box to the right a little more so it looks better.

Answer (score 0):

You can set:

```
position: absolute;
```

on it, then move it around using `top: y px` and `left: x px`. Note, however; position absolute will take the box out of normal flow.

Like this:

```
 .ConversionBox2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    color: #004284;
    padding: 15px;
    /* Border Radius Style */
    border-radius: 15px;
   /* Mozilla Firefox Extension */
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  }
```

Comment: Remove `float: left` and add `.conversionBox2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 60px; }` to your style. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try css [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.box-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
.horizontal-align {
  justify-content: center;
}
.vertical-align {
  align-items: center;
}
.left-align {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.right-align {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.center-align {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="container horizontal-align">Horizontal</div>
  <div class="container vertical-align">Vertical</div>
  <div class="container left-align">Left</div>
  <div class="container right-align">Right</div>
  <div class="container center-align">Center</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending if your box is in another div and what within the .ConversionBox2 you want to the right, try the following

```
padding-left: (number) px;
// will push the content in the .ConversionBox2 to the right
// padding maybe also be specified like
// padding: (top px) (right px) (bottom px) (left px);
margin-left: (number) px;
// will push the .ConversionBox2 to the right
// also can be written like
// margin: (top px) (right px) (bottom px) (left px);
```

If you are interested, you can also look at relative and absolute positioning to get this box where you want.